# SQL Access 2010 querying by date "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

Tags: sql, date

I'm trying to make a query in Access 2010, but it keeps giving me this error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

The query is simple as

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE date = '23-07-2013'
```

Any wonder why?

Comment: Access enclosed a date with # signs to indicate a literal value of date.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE date = #7/23/2013#
```

Answer (score 10):

Access enclosed a date with # signs to indicate a literal value of date. And using a single quote in your case means you are comparing a String/Text with a Date data type thus the Data Type mismatch. It should therefore be:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM mytable
 WHERE date = #23/07/2013#
```

Comment: And does this only happen in Access? I mean, do I have to enclose dates with # even in e.g. mySQL?

Comment: AFAIK in Access only in mySQL single quote would be fine.